# Finding Prime Numbers between Two Numbers

Tags: c++

Am trying to find all prime numbers between two given numbers and sum the primes up.

I have this loop that does the prime number detection correctly.

However, for some reason I don't know how to sum all the primes.

```
int a,b,i,j,sum=0;

do
{   cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;
    if (a < 4 || a > 1000000) 
    {   cout << "Input must be between 4 and 1000000 inclusive." << endl;
    }
}while (a < 4 || a > 1000000);

do
{   cout << "Enter a second number: ";
    cin >> b;
    if (b < 4 || b > 1000000) 
    {   cout << "Input must be between 4 and 1000000 inclusive." << endl;
    }
}while (b < 4 || b > 1000000);

if (a > b)
{   int hold;
    hold = b;
    b = a;
    a = hold;
}

cout << "The prime numbers between " << a << " and " << b << " inclusive are: " << endl;
//int sum;
for (i = a; i <= b; i++)
{
 for (j = 2; j <= i; j++) // Changed the < to <=, and got rid of semicolon
 {
    if (!(i%j)&&(i!=j)) break;
    if (j==i) 
    {
              cout << i << endl;
              sum += i;
              cout << sum ;

    }
 }
}
```

The variable `sum` gives me rubbish results.

Comment: Fix your formatting and use sensible variable names, thank you ...

Comment: did you initialize it (`sum`) to zero? what is the range? what is the type of `sum`? You could also be encountering an overflow, depending on the range.

Comment: i'd made that actually 

    int sum = 0 ;

Comment: Your outer `for` loop has no ending brace.

Comment: if this problem .. it wasn't run 

it is run

Comment: Good point. I'd really recommend taking a look at amit's updates though.

Comment: In the second for loop you just need run it upto sqrt(j).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to know without the exact details but two most likely possibilities are:

1. `sum` was not initialized to 0 prior to usage
2. You are encountering an [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), since the sum of numbers is too large to fit in it. It obviously depends on the type of `sum`, and the range.

EDIT:

The editted code works for me, for small ranges (note that for larger ranges, one should also consider issue #2).

You might be misreading the results, try adding `endl` to `cout << sum ;`

Comment: i'd initialized it with zero already 

still give me this result

Comment: How big are your numbers `a` and `b`?

Comment: @Mahmoud: At least or small ranges - it works for me. Maybe you misreading the results because you forgot `endl` in: `cout << sum ;` ?

Comment: @amit, that's exactly what I was thinking after running it. Going from 5 to 8, you see `5 57 12`.

Comment: Thanks @amit .. i don't know how is endl fix it 

the result was strange zeros and numbers 


On the whole .. thanks ,,,,

Comment: @Mahmoud, you'd have seen `i` concatenated with `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you gave us all information. Otherwise, for me it seems that you did not initialize `sum`.

```
int sum = 0;
for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    for (j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
        if (!(i%j)&&(i!=j)) 
            break;

        if (j==i) { 
            cout << i << endl;
            sum += i;
            cout << sum;
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to simply be your formatting.  Change the end loop to the following, and the output will be much clearer (note: in your code, sum2 is not declared - I added "int sum2 = 0" above all of this)

```
for (i = a; i <= b; i++)
{
    for (j = 2; j <= i; j++) // Changed the < to <=, and got rid of semicolon
    {
        if (!(i%j) && (i!=j)) break;
        if (j==i) 
        {
            cout << "i = " << i << endl;
            sum += i;
            cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;

        }
        sum2 += sum ;
        //cout << "sum2 = " << sum2 << endl;
    }
}
```